# Show full image in contacts after add contact using openContactForm

Tags: image, react-native, react-native-contacts

I am using openContactForm API of React-Native-Contacts in react-native. It's working well and I can send image url for the thumbnail of contact and it's working well.
The minor thing is image is not showing as correctly and the image has cropped some area in left and right.
Please help me how can I solve this problem.
Thank you

Comment: What platform are you seeing those issues on? ios or android?

Comment: This issue is about 6 months ago and I have already solved this problem.

Comment: What was your solution so it helps other people.